# Confusion about Notation of the Cardinality of a Set

Tags: real-analysis, functions, elementary-set-theory, notation, equivalence-relations

One textbook I'm reading says that the definition of two sets having the same cardinality is as follows:

"*Two sets A and B have the same cardinality if there exists a bijection $f:A \rightarrow B$.*"

It also says that $|A|$ denotes the equivalence class of all sets having the same cardinality of A. So since equivalence classes in general are sets, then that would mean that $|A|$ is a set.

However later on, the textbook wants us to write $|A| = n$ if $A$ has the same cardinality as the set {$1, 2, ..., n$}. Doesn't that contradict the whole meaning of $|A|$ being an equivalence relation then, since $n$ is not a set but instead a natural number?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In set theory, natural numbers are sets.

Comment: Yes, that sounds like bad notation- using the same symbol for two different things.  I haven't looked at that book.  Are you sure they are exactly the same?

Comment: I know, but I'm not talking about the set of natural numbers, $\mathbb N$. I'm talking about the number $n \in \mathbb N$, in which $n$ is an arbitrary natural number.

Comment: @user247327 Yes, it is the exact same symbol. The book is called "Basic Analysis" by Jiří Lebl.

Answer (score 2):

Set theory does not allow one to form a set out of all sets with cardinality $3$, say. Nor even a set of all sets with any given cardinality (*except* for the cardinality $0$, for which $\{\{\}\}$ does the trick). The existence of such a set would contradict the axioms of set theory, in a manner similar to Russell's paradox. So no, it is not true that "equivalence classes in general are sets".

This leaves one with the problem: Is there a way to sidestep this issue? Perhaps some way to *naturally* choose a single set in each "equivalence class"? Perhaps even a way to *define* cardinal numbers by making such a choice in some set theoretically natural manner?

This problem is solved by a lot of things with John Von Neumann's name attached to them: the [Von Neumann notation for natural numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-theoretic_definition_of_natural_numbers#Definition_as_von_Neumann_ordinals), and more generally the [Von Neumann notation for ordinal numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number#Von_Neumann_definition_of_ordinals), coupled with the [Von Neumann assignment for cardinal numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_cardinal_assignment).

Comment: I don't get the part where you say that it's not true that equivalence classes in general are sets. In the textbook I'm reading, it says that for an element $a$ in some set $A$ for an equivalence relation R, the equivalence class of $a$, denoted $[a]$, is defined as the *set* {$x \in A | x R a$}. So wouldn't that definition be wrong then?

Comment: The problem is also solved by Scott's trick, which (unlike von Neumann's) works in the absence of the axiom of choice (but needs the axiom of regularity). The trick, due to Dana Scott, is to define $|A|$ as the set of all sets that (1) admit bijections to $A$ and (2) are of the lowest possible rank (subject to (1)).

Comment: @Tim: That definition assumes that you have a set to begin with, namely the set $A$.

Comment: @Tim If you start with a set, like the $A$ in your comment, then the equivalence classes will also be sets. If, on the other hand, you start with the whole universe, as when you introduce cardinalities in the question, then the equivalence classes might fail to be sets.

Comment: @LeeMosher Exactly, so |A| is based on the set A. So the definition of an equivalence relation would be applied, wouldn't it?

Comment: I'm confused though, because why couldn't they just mention it in the textbook then? They haven't even covered the axioms yet and I still don't know about them.

Comment: It seems like you are confusing two different usages of the notation $A$. The cardinality of $A$ is *not* an equivalence class of any relation *on the set $A$ itself*. I believe that the author is trying to get across the idea that the cardinality $|A|$ is the equivalence class of a relation *on the entire universe of all sets*, namely $|A|$ is equal to the **class** of all sets $B$ for which there exists a bijection $f : A \to B$.

Comment: But this definition of $|A|$ is unsatisfactory if you want $|A|$ to exist as a set. Hence the Von Neumann definition (or the Scott definition mentioned by @AndreasBlass).

Comment: It's not unreasonable to be confused about all this is you've never seen the axioms of set theory. So my suggestion is: Think critically regarding what the author says about $|A|$; Beware of Russell's paradox and its cousins; and enjoy the Von Neumann definitions.

Comment: I'll have a think about that. Thanks for the help.